# div onclick inside anchor tag

Tags: javascript, html, onclick, anchor

I have a code like this:

```
<a href="somewhere.html">
<img src="blabla">
<div class="wrap">
    <div id="id1" onclick="window.location = 'somepage1.html';"></div>
    <div id="id2" onclick="window.location = 'somepage2.html';"></div>
<div>
</a>
```

The problem is that the div's onclick is not working. When I click on div's I go to somewhere.html.

Comment: sorry .. I have corrected this typo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have wrong html structure wrapping divs inside link (unless using html5):

```
<a href="somewhere.html">
<img src="blabla">
<div class="wrap">
    <div id="id1" onclick="window.location = 'somepage1.html';"></div>
    <div id="id2" onclick="window.location = 'somepage2.html';"</div>
<div>
</a>
```

When you click, you will always go to link at top `somewhere.html` and inner divs won't do what you want to do. You should modify your html structure.

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="somewhere.html" onclick = "return false;">
<img src="blabla">
<div class="wrap">
  <div id="id1" onclick="window.location = 'somepage1.html';"></div>
  <div id="id2" onclick="window.location = 'somepage2.html';"</div>
<div>
</a>
```

Comment: remove divs from the link then, why do you need to put them in the link if they go to another url?

Comment: Because of the image. I have a image inside a href. Over the image I have some text that I need to be clickable.

Comment: The divs are buttons. So ... I have a clickable picture with some buttons over it

Comment: you can add a style of cursor:pointer in css. if you need a hand to appear.

Comment: The cursor:pointer is not the problem. The problem is that the picture link points to the picture view page. The buttons over the picture points to different pages. One points to delete page and other to edit page.